# Python with selenium: unable to locate element which really exists

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, selenium3, training

I've been trying to fill input:

```
<input id="PASSFIELD1" class="logField" type="password" onkeyup="next(this, event);" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" name="PASSFIELD1"></input>
```

To do this, I have to find this element.

I tried below things:

```
1. pass1=driver.find_element_by_name("PASSFIELD1")
```

```
2. pass1=driver.find_element_by_id("PASSFIELD1")
```

```
3. pass1= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input[1]") (path from firebug)
```

4. Even wait 100 seconds for it

```
self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input[1]")))

self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/input[1]"))
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 'Unable to locate element: (...)
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Look more into the DOM - is there an iframe? Is it shadow DOM?

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for an element before trying to interact with it. There are generally two options and do not mix use of the two.

1. Use [implicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

2. Use [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```